# How to set STM32 to generate standard CRC32

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32, crc32

I am trying to generate CRC with STM32L4 hardware modul. I would like to validate fatfs files so basically I have byte arrays. I am using this CRC [generator](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html).

Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to set STM32L4 to generate the same result. I need CRC32 and I have

configuration:

```
hcrc.Instance = CRC;

/* The default polynomial is not used. It is required to defined it in CrcHandle.Init.GeneratingPolynomial*/
hcrc.Init.DefaultPolynomialUse    = DEFAULT_POLYNOMIAL_DISABLE;
/* Set the value of the polynomial */
hcrc.Init.GeneratingPolynomial    = 0x4C11DB7;
//hcrc.Init.GeneratingPolynomial    = 0xFB3EE248;
hcrc.Init.CRCLength= CRC_POLYLENGTH_32B;
/* The default init value is used */
/* The default init value is not used */
hcrc.Init.DefaultInitValueUse     = DEFAULT_INIT_VALUE_ENABLE;

/* User init value is used instead */
//hcrc.Init.InitValue               = 0;
hcrc.Init.InputDataInversionMode = CRC_INPUTDATA_INVERSION_NONE;
//hcrc.Init.InputDataInversionMode = CRC_INPUTDATA_INVERSION_BYTE;
/* The input data are inverted by word */
//hcrc.Init.InputDataInversionMode  = CRC_INPUTDATA_INVERSION_WORD;

//hcrc.Init.OutputDataInversionMode = CRC_OUTPUTDATA_INVERSION_ENABLE;
hcrc.Init.OutputDataInversionMode = CRC_OUTPUTDATA_INVERSION_DISABLE;
hcrc.InputDataFormat = CRC_INPUTDATA_FORMAT_BYTES;
HAL_CRC_Init(&hcrc);
```

testing:

```
uint8_t test[] = {49,50,51,52};
uint32_t uwCRCValue = HAL_CRC_Calculate(&hcrc,(uint32_t *) test, 4);
```

result: `A695C4AA`

I am out of ideas. There is one way that I am succeeded with it to have `uint32_t test[]` and input is set to `hcrc.InputDataFormat = CRC_INPUTDATA_FORMAT_BYTES;` 
Unfortunately I have `uint8_t`...

Comment: Did you remember to enable the CRC peripheral clock?  Your code doesn't show it.

Comment: Have you read appropriate reference manual? CRC module have advanced settings for different endianness cases. If you have right result with uint32_t test[], so problem only in endianness settings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I have checked them (I used CubeMX code generator). I have read the reference manual. Unfortunately no combination of settings give me any of the CRC32 calculated by standard algorithms.

Comment: You've gotta mention people if you want them to see your comment. You're the opener, so you receive your posts' comments without being mentioned. To mention people, add @ before their name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code to calc cc32. CRC32 calc by STM32 CRC unit is not the same as our standard CRC32, it did use big endian, and it will not XOR with 0xFFFFFFFF.

```
u32 CRC32_ForBytes(u8 *pData, u32 uLen);

#define UNUSED(x) ((void)(x))

/**
 * @brief  CRC functions
 */
#define __HAL_RCC_CRC_CLK_ENABLE()   do { \
                                        __IO uint32_t tmpreg; \
                                        SET_BIT(RCC->AHBENR, RCC_AHBENR_CRCEN);\
                                        /* Delay after an RCC peripheral clock enabling */\
                                        tmpreg = READ_BIT(RCC->AHBENR, RCC_AHBENR_CRCEN);\
                                        UNUSED(tmpreg); \
                                      } while(0)

#define __HAL_RCC_CRC_CLK_DISABLE()       (RCC->AHBENR &= ~(RCC_AHBENR_CRCEN))

#define CRC32_POLYNOMIAL                        ((u32)0xEDB88320)  
#define RCC_CRC_BIT                             ((u32)0x00001000)


/**
 * @brief  Calc CRC32 for data in bytes
 * @param  pData Buffer pointer
 * @param  uLen  Buffer Length
 * @retval CRC32 Checksum
 */
u32 CRC32_ForBytes(u8 *pData,u32 uLen)  
{  
    u32 uIndex= 0,uData = 0,i;  
    uIndex = uLen >> 2;  

    __HAL_RCC_CRC_CLK_ENABLE();

    /* Reset CRC generator */  
    CRC_ResetDR();

    while(uIndex--)  
    {  
#ifdef USED_BIG_ENDIAN    
        uData = __REV((u32*)pData);  
#else
        ((u8 *)&uData)[0] = pData[0];
        ((u8 *)&uData)[1] = pData[1];
        ((u8 *)&uData)[2] = pData[2];
        ((u8 *)&uData)[3] = pData[3];
#endif        
        pData += 4;  
        uData = revbit(uData);  
        CRC->DR = uData;  
    }  
    uData = revbit(CRC->DR);  
    uIndex = uLen & 0x03;  
    while(uIndex--)  
    {  
        uData ^= (u32)*pData++;  
        for(i = 0;i < 8;i++)  
          if (uData & 0x1)  
            uData = (uData >> 1) ^ CRC32_POLYNOMIAL;  
          else  
            uData >>= 1;  
    }

    __HAL_RCC_CRC_CLK_DISABLE();

    return uData^0xFFFFFFFF;  
}

static u32 revbit(u32 uData)
{  
    u32 uRevData = 0,uIndex = 0;  
    uRevData |= ((uData >> uIndex) & 0x01);  
    for(uIndex = 1;uIndex < 32;uIndex++)  
    {  
        uRevData <<= 1;  
        uRevData |= ((uData >> uIndex) & 0x01);  
    }  
    return uRevData;  
}
```

Calc your CRC32 like this:

```
u32 uwCRCValue = CRC32_ForBytes(&test, 4);
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. My main goal was to use the hardware calculator. I successfully generated the same output with this algorithm on PC side [CRC32 C# code](https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/cortex_mx_stm32/DispForm.aspx?ID=44842&Source=/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Tags.aspx?tags=CRC32)
On hardware site it works with:
'uint32_t test[] = {49,50,51,52};'
But if I change to:
'uint8_t test[] = {49,50,51,52};' 
the result changed and still can't find the right algorithm. It could by a padding problem but I used 4 bytes to test. I have ended up using a checksum.

Comment: CRC is essentially the remainder after a very long long-division so the order of the input data bytes does matter. The input data bytes are like an extremely long number as far as the CRC algorithm is concerned.

Comment: At least the STM32L4 supports reversing the input data. So you are able to choose whether the hardware processes the data in big or little endian fashion. As is, this answer is wrong.

Comment: This suggested algorithm is actually 100% correct and matches any standard CRC32 for any arbitrary length data (including cases when (uLen % 4) > 0). In addition, I would recommend using `__RBIT(uData)` operation, which allows reversing bit order in the whole 32 bit word in 1 tick on ARM MCU;

Comment: This seems like a lot of code considering that the CRC peripheral is supposed to do most of the work needed. Maybe this could be modified to avoid having to copy the data into temporary memory?

Answer (score 13):

Using CubeMX, I generated with these settings:

```
hcrc.Instance = CRC;
hcrc.Init.DefaultPolynomialUse = DEFAULT_POLYNOMIAL_ENABLE;
hcrc.Init.DefaultInitValueUse = DEFAULT_INIT_VALUE_ENABLE;
hcrc.Init.InputDataInversionMode = CRC_INPUTDATA_INVERSION_BYTE;
hcrc.Init.OutputDataInversionMode = CRC_OUTPUTDATA_INVERSION_ENABLE;
hcrc.InputDataFormat = CRC_INPUTDATA_FORMAT_BYTES;
```

Calculate the CRC like so:

```
uint32_t crc = HAL_CRC_Calculate(&hcrc, (uint32_t *)address, length);
```

And finally invert:

```
crc = ~crc;
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your suggestions. Unfortunately I cannot try your solution the project is not on my desk anymore.
As far as I can remember my problem was that I cannot reproduce the same result(CRC) as STM for the same input on PC side. Tried to calculate result for example with this site http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html but cannot get the same result.

Comment: And one more thing came into my mind. I tried to use uint8_t array as an input with CRC_INPUTDATA_FORMAT_BYTES option. I cannot manage to get the same result as on PC. Then I used uint32_t array with the same 8 bit data in it and the correct result evaluated. So I ended up to use bigger arrray uint32_t[] instead of uint8_t[] and I could use the standard calculation algorith on PC side.

Comment: @DavidMolnar Did you test `uint32_t uwCRCValue = HAL_CRC_Calculate(&hcrc,(uint32_t *) test, 1);`? 1 = length of 8-bits data array (4) / 4

Comment: I confirm this is working and outputting standard CRC32, this final invert is critical. Also, you don't need divide the length of data with 4 if you set `CRC_INPUTDATA_FORMAT_BYTES` as the HAL does that for you, kind of. I used this code `uint32_t uwCRCValue = ~HAL_CRC_Calculate(&hcrc, (uint32_t *) msg, strlen(msg));`

Answer (score 5):

This works for me.

```
static CRC_HandleTypeDef hcrc = { 
    .Instance = CRC, 
    .Init.DefaultPolynomialUse = DEFAULT_POLYNOMIAL_ENABLE,
    .Init.DefaultInitValueUse = DEFAULT_INIT_VALUE_ENABLE,
    .Init.CRCLength = CRC_POLYLENGTH_32B,
    .Init.InputDataInversionMode = CRC_INPUTDATA_INVERSION_NONE,
    .Init.OutputDataInversionMode = CRC_OUTPUTDATA_INVERSION_DISABLE,
    .InputDataFormat = CRC_INPUTDATA_FORMAT_BYTES,
};
```

And the manual method

```
static const uint32_t crc_table[0x100] = {
  0x00000000, 0x04C11DB7, 0x09823B6E, 0x0D4326D9, 0x130476DC, 0x17C56B6B, 0x1A864DB2, 0x1E475005, 0x2608EDB8, 0x22C9F00F, 0x2F8AD6D6, 0x2B4BCB61, 0x350C9B64, 0x31CD86D3, 0x3C8EA00A, 0x384FBDBD, 
  0x4C11DB70, 0x48D0C6C7, 0x4593E01E, 0x4152FDA9, 0x5F15ADAC, 0x5BD4B01B, 0x569796C2, 0x52568B75, 0x6A1936C8, 0x6ED82B7F, 0x639B0DA6, 0x675A1011, 0x791D4014, 0x7DDC5DA3, 0x709F7B7A, 0x745E66CD, 
  0x9823B6E0, 0x9CE2AB57, 0x91A18D8E, 0x95609039, 0x8B27C03C, 0x8FE6DD8B, 0x82A5FB52, 0x8664E6E5, 0xBE2B5B58, 0xBAEA46EF, 0xB7A96036, 0xB3687D81, 0xAD2F2D84, 0xA9EE3033, 0xA4AD16EA, 0xA06C0B5D, 
  0xD4326D90, 0xD0F37027, 0xDDB056FE, 0xD9714B49, 0xC7361B4C, 0xC3F706FB, 0xCEB42022, 0xCA753D95, 0xF23A8028, 0xF6FB9D9F, 0xFBB8BB46, 0xFF79A6F1, 0xE13EF6F4, 0xE5FFEB43, 0xE8BCCD9A, 0xEC7DD02D, 
  0x34867077, 0x30476DC0, 0x3D044B19, 0x39C556AE, 0x278206AB, 0x23431B1C, 0x2E003DC5, 0x2AC12072, 0x128E9DCF, 0x164F8078, 0x1B0CA6A1, 0x1FCDBB16, 0x018AEB13, 0x054BF6A4, 0x0808D07D, 0x0CC9CDCA, 
  0x7897AB07, 0x7C56B6B0, 0x71159069, 0x75D48DDE, 0x6B93DDDB, 0x6F52C06C, 0x6211E6B5, 0x66D0FB02, 0x5E9F46BF, 0x5A5E5B08, 0x571D7DD1, 0x53DC6066, 0x4D9B3063, 0x495A2DD4, 0x44190B0D, 0x40D816BA, 
  0xACA5C697, 0xA864DB20, 0xA527FDF9, 0xA1E6E04E, 0xBFA1B04B, 0xBB60ADFC, 0xB6238B25, 0xB2E29692, 0x8AAD2B2F, 0x8E6C3698, 0x832F1041, 0x87EE0DF6, 0x99A95DF3, 0x9D684044, 0x902B669D, 0x94EA7B2A, 
  0xE0B41DE7, 0xE4750050, 0xE9362689, 0xEDF73B3E, 0xF3B06B3B, 0xF771768C, 0xFA325055, 0xFEF34DE2, 0xC6BCF05F, 0xC27DEDE8, 0xCF3ECB31, 0xCBFFD686, 0xD5B88683, 0xD1799B34, 0xDC3ABDED, 0xD8FBA05A, 
  0x690CE0EE, 0x6DCDFD59, 0x608EDB80, 0x644FC637, 0x7A089632, 0x7EC98B85, 0x738AAD5C, 0x774BB0EB, 0x4F040D56, 0x4BC510E1, 0x46863638, 0x42472B8F, 0x5C007B8A, 0x58C1663D, 0x558240E4, 0x51435D53, 
  0x251D3B9E, 0x21DC2629, 0x2C9F00F0, 0x285E1D47, 0x36194D42, 0x32D850F5, 0x3F9B762C, 0x3B5A6B9B, 0x0315D626, 0x07D4CB91, 0x0A97ED48, 0x0E56F0FF, 0x1011A0FA, 0x14D0BD4D, 0x19939B94, 0x1D528623, 
  0xF12F560E, 0xF5EE4BB9, 0xF8AD6D60, 0xFC6C70D7, 0xE22B20D2, 0xE6EA3D65, 0xEBA91BBC, 0xEF68060B, 0xD727BBB6, 0xD3E6A601, 0xDEA580D8, 0xDA649D6F, 0xC423CD6A, 0xC0E2D0DD, 0xCDA1F604, 0xC960EBB3, 
  0xBD3E8D7E, 0xB9FF90C9, 0xB4BCB610, 0xB07DABA7, 0xAE3AFBA2, 0xAAFBE615, 0xA7B8C0CC, 0xA379DD7B, 0x9B3660C6, 0x9FF77D71, 0x92B45BA8, 0x9675461F, 0x8832161A, 0x8CF30BAD, 0x81B02D74, 0x857130C3, 
  0x5D8A9099, 0x594B8D2E, 0x5408ABF7, 0x50C9B640, 0x4E8EE645, 0x4A4FFBF2, 0x470CDD2B, 0x43CDC09C, 0x7B827D21, 0x7F436096, 0x7200464F, 0x76C15BF8, 0x68860BFD, 0x6C47164A, 0x61043093, 0x65C52D24, 
  0x119B4BE9, 0x155A565E, 0x18197087, 0x1CD86D30, 0x029F3D35, 0x065E2082, 0x0B1D065B, 0x0FDC1BEC, 0x3793A651, 0x3352BBE6, 0x3E119D3F, 0x3AD08088, 0x2497D08D, 0x2056CD3A, 0x2D15EBE3, 0x29D4F654, 
  0xC5A92679, 0xC1683BCE, 0xCC2B1D17, 0xC8EA00A0, 0xD6AD50A5, 0xD26C4D12, 0xDF2F6BCB, 0xDBEE767C, 0xE3A1CBC1, 0xE760D676, 0xEA23F0AF, 0xEEE2ED18, 0xF0A5BD1D, 0xF464A0AA, 0xF9278673, 0xFDE69BC4, 
  0x89B8FD09, 0x8D79E0BE, 0x803AC667, 0x84FBDBD0, 0x9ABC8BD5, 0x9E7D9662, 0x933EB0BB, 0x97FFAD0C, 0xAFB010B1, 0xAB710D06, 0xA6322BDF, 0xA2F33668, 0xBCB4666D, 0xB8757BDA, 0xB5365D03, 0xB1F740B4, 
};

uint32_t CalcCRC(uint8_t * pData, uint32_t DataLength)
{
    uint32_t Checksum = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < DataLength; i++)
    {
        uint8_t top = (uint8_t)(Checksum >> 24);
        top ^= pData[i];
        Checksum = (Checksum << 8) ^ crc_table[top];
    }
    return Checksum;
}
```

Comment: Note that when using the hardware CRC calculation there is a significant performance increase using 32 bit words rather then bytes.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation should be very simple when using the peripheral--basically a loop running:

```c
*(uint8_t*)&CRC->DR = buffer[i];
```

The tricky parts are getting the options set right (bit flipping, initial value, polynomial to use, XOR'ing result, etc.) and making sure to access the data register at the appropriate data width (i.e., to instruct it to operate on 1, 2, or 4 bytes at a time). https://crccalc.com/ helpfully shows the variations that you'll get depending on whether bit order is reversed, output has bits XOR'd, etc. I suggest testing your implementation with a few arbitrary bytes and comparing the result with the table produced by that site for the same data.

Here's my implementation for reference:

```c
#include "stm32g4xx_hal.h" // change, as appropriate, for your MCU
#include <stdlib.h>

uint32_t crc32(uint8_t *buffer, size_t size) {
  // If the clock was turned on previously and kept on then it isn't necessary to do that here each time.
  // Did it here to match ST's example in AN4187 (page 8)
  // https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00068118-using-the-crc-peripheral-in-the-stm32-family-stmicroelectronics.pdf)
  __HAL_RCC_CRC_CLK_ENABLE();
  // For standard (Ethernet) CRC-32 bit order is reversed on input and output
  CRC->CR = CRC_CR_REV_IN_0 | CRC_CR_REV_IN_1 | CRC_CR_REV_OUT;
  // The initial value and polynomial are set up during initialization.
  // Conveniently, in my case, the reset values are already correct:
  //CRC->INIT = 0xFFFFFFFF;
  //CRC->POL = 0x04C11DB7;
  CRC->CR |= CRC_CR_RESET;
  uint32_t i = 0;
  // First work on as many full 32-bit words as we can
  uint32_t full_word_bytes = size & 0b11;
  while (i < full_word_bytes) {
    CRC->DR = *(uint32_t*)&buffer[i];
    i += 4;
  }
  // Now handle any additional bytes one at a time
  while (i < size) {
    // Here we are using 8-bit access to the CRC peripheral's data register
    // so it does not introduce padding into the computation.
    // (e.g. the CRC of 4 zeros is different than for only 1)
    *(uint8_t*)&CRC->DR = buffer[i];
    i++;
  }
  // For standard (Ethernet) CRC-32 output bits need to all flip
  i = CRC->DR ^ 0xFFFFFFFF;
  __HAL_RCC_CRC_CLK_DISABLE();
  return i;
}

// Can test like this:
uint8_t crc_test_in[] = { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x90 };
uint32_t expected_crc = 0xDC936EB1;
uint32_t crc = crc32(crc_test_in, sizeof(crc_test_in)/sizeof(crc_test_in[0]));
// ... print / compare ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a small note if you are wondering what polynomial `hcrc.Init.GeneratingPolynomial` and `hcrc.Init.CRCLength` means. In your initial example, your polynomial settings will give:

```
> polyviz(0x4C11DB7, 32)
x^32 + x^26 + x^23 + x^22 + x^16 + x^12 + x^11 + x^10 + x^8 + x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x^1 + 1
```

If you got node.js installed, you can use the below function I written to convert from stm32 crc generator polynomial to crc polynomial formula `...+x^2+x^1+1` form.

```
function polyviz(Pol, PolyLength)
{
  var msb = 31;

  process.stdout.write(" x^"+(PolyLength));
  while (msb-- > 0)
  {
    if ((Pol & (1 << msb)))
    {
      if (msb == 0)
      process.stdout.write(" + 1");
      else
      process.stdout.write(" + x^"+(msb));
    }
  }
  process.stdout.write("\r\n");
}

// Examples from HAL_CRCEx_Polynomial_Set():
// * for a polynomial of degree 16, X^16 + X^12 + X^5 + 1 is written 0x1021 (Bin: 0001 0000 0010 0001 )
polyviz(0x1021, 16)
// * for a polynomial of degree 7, X^7 + X^6 + X^5 + X^2 + 1 is written 0x65 (Bin: 0110 0101)
polyviz(0x65, 7)
```

Using this method, you can confirm if you set your polynomial correctly. (Since many crc standards uses polynomial representation)

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial (for STM32F746) and use it with STM32F407VGT6,

There are a lot of IDE configurations and it will probably be better to access them directly, I'm sorry I don't embed all the content directly here:

[Hands-on: CRC Checksum Generation](https://github.com/ethanhuanginst/STM32CubeIDE-Workshop-2019/blob/master/hands-on/06_F746-DISCO-CRC/README.md)

Note: In this case, the file to be written is ROM.hex (you will need to configure the STM32CubeIDE to be able to do this operation **automatically**, the IDE uses the *.elf file, see how to do it in the tips below):

[Some tips and solutions about this CRC usage (Windows/Linux)](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00001Z9UUUSA3/bug-why-is-the-ide-190-preventing-hex-file-selection-instead-of-elf)

Answer (score 0):

For STM32F103, with hardware CRC generator enabled (in STM cube or manual), use this procedure:

```
uint32_t RealCRC32(uint32_t * buf, uint32_t len) //demesio, kas 4 baitai!
{
uint32_t crc,tmp,i;
      hcrc.State = HAL_CRC_STATE_BUSY;
    __HAL_CRC_DR_RESET(&hcrc);

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        tmp=buf[i];
        tmp = __RBIT(tmp);
        hcrc.Instance->DR = tmp;
    }   
    crc = __RBIT(hcrc.Instance->DR);
    hcrc.State = HAL_CRC_STATE_READY;
    return crc;
}
```

Note: CRC32 is for 32 bit wide data. If it is byte buffer, make sure that it is in 4 byte increments. Otherwise it will be buffer overrun and some wrong CRC.
For "typical CRC" invert the result `crc=~RealCRC32(ptr,100);`

Note: byte and bit order is important! Different hardware may flip bytes in words.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to show how the `HAL_CRC_Calculate` is working (`STM32F407`, `STM32F107`, etc.) and how to do the same calculation by yourself:

```
uint32_t Crc32(uint32_t Crc, uint32_t Data) {
    uint8_t i;

    Crc = Crc ^ Data;

    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        Crc = Crc & 0x80000000 ? (Crc << 1) ^ 0x04C11DB7 : Crc << 1; // Polynomial used in STM32
    return Crc;
}

void test_crc(void) {
    uint8_t i;
    uint8_t amountofdata;
    uint32_t data[4] = {
        0x12345678,
        0x23456789,
        0x3456789A,
        0x456789AB,
    };
    uint32_t crc_polynom;
    uint32_t crc_cal1 = 0;
    uint32_t crc_cal2 = 0;

    // 1x4bytes
    amountofdata = 1;
    crc_polynom = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    crc_cal1 = HAL_CRC_Calculate(&hcrc, &data[0], amountofdata);
    crc_cal2 = Crc32(crc_polynom, data[0]);

    if (crc_cal1 != crc_cal2)
        Error_Handler();

    // 2x4bytes
    amountofdata = 2;
    crc_polynom = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    crc_cal1 = HAL_CRC_Calculate(&hcrc, &data[0], amountofdata);

    for (i = 0; i < amountofdata; i++)
        crc_polynom = Crc32(crc_polynom, data[i]);
    crc_cal2 = crc_polynom;
    if (crc_cal1 != crc_cal2)
        Error_Handler();

    // 4x4bytes
    amountofdata = 4;
    crc_polynom = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    crc_cal1 = HAL_CRC_Calculate(&hcrc, &data[0], amountofdata);
    
    for (i = 0; i < amountofdata; i++)
        crc_polynom = Crc32(crc_polynom, data[i]);
    crc_cal2 = crc_polynom;

    if (crc_cal1 != crc_cal2)
        Error_Handler();

    // 2x4bytes
    uint8_t rxbuff[8] = {
        0x01,
        0x02,
        0x0c,
        0x0a,
        0x1a,
        0x01,
        0x03,
        0x01,
    };

    amountofdata = 2;
    crc_polynom = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    crc_cal1 = HAL_CRC_Calculate(&hcrc, (uint32_t*)&rxbuff[0], amountofdata);

    for (i = 0; i < amountofdata << 2;)
    {
        crc_polynom = Crc32(crc_polynom, *(uint32_t*)&rxbuff[i]);
        i += 4;
    }
    crc_cal2 = crc_polynom;

    if (crc_cal1 != crc_cal2)
        Error_Handler();
}
```