# Improve Python code/ STM CRC32 function

Tags: python, performance, crc, crc32

I have function to calculate STM crc32 of bytes array. The problem is that for 5120 byte array it takes 20ms which is definitely too long. There is an option to improve speed of this code, it can max takes about 5ms??

code :

```
def crc32_stm(bytes_arr):

    length = len(bytes_arr)
    crc = 0xffffffff

    k = 0
    while length >= 4:

        v = ((bytes_arr[k] << 24) & 0xFF000000) | ((bytes_arr[k+1] << 16) & 0xFF0000) | \
        ((bytes_arr[k+2] << 8) & 0xFF00) | (bytes_arr[k+3] & 0xFF)

        crc = ((crc << 8) & 0xffffffff) ^ custom_crc_table[0xFF & ((crc >> 24) ^ v)]
        crc = ((crc << 8) & 0xffffffff) ^ custom_crc_table[0xFF & ((crc >> 24) ^ (v >> 8))]
        crc = ((crc << 8) & 0xffffffff) ^ custom_crc_table[0xFF & ((crc >> 24) ^ (v >> 16))]
        crc = ((crc << 8) & 0xffffffff) ^ custom_crc_table[0xFF & ((crc >> 24) ^ (v >> 24))]

        k += 4
        length -= 4

    if length > 0:
        v = 0

        for i in range(length):
            v |= (bytes_arr[k+i] << 24-i*8)

        if length == 1:
            v &= 0xFF000000

        elif length == 2:
            v &= 0xFFFF0000

        elif length == 3:
            v &= 0xFFFFFF00

        crc = (( crc << 8 ) & 0xffffffff) ^ custom_crc_table[0xFF & ( (crc >> 24) ^ (v ) )];
        crc = (( crc << 8 ) & 0xffffffff) ^ custom_crc_table[0xFF & ( (crc >> 24) ^ (v >> 8) )];
        crc = (( crc << 8 ) & 0xffffffff) ^ custom_crc_table[0xFF & ( (crc >> 24) ^ (v >> 16) )];
        crc = (( crc << 8 ) & 0xffffffff) ^ custom_crc_table[0xFF & ( (crc >> 24) ^ (v >> 24) )];

    global stmCrc
    stmCrc = crc
    return crc
```

Comment: have you tried using the `binascii.crc32` function? not sure if you want signed or unsigned, that function gives signed, and to turn to unsigned: `crc32 = binascii.crc32(data) % (1<<32)`

Comment: binascii give just crc not stm crc so I can't use binascii or zlib

Comment: What's in the table?

Comment: If your code is already working, consider posting on [Code Review.SE](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: STM chips can be configured for the usual zlib CRC32 (as opposed to the default MPEG2 CRC32). More information in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064278/matching-crc32-from-stm32f0-and-zlib

Answer (score 2):

You can use [crcmod](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crcmod) to generate C code that you compile and then call from Python. That will be orders of magnitude faster than the Python code.

Comment: And it will calculate STM crc ?

Comment: Ok i check it i use it before and it gives me other crc not stm

Comment: You provide the CRC parameters. It can generate code for _any_ CRC with a length that is a multiple of 8 and <= 64 (which includes 32).